# How to fix PCIE errors after reboot / shutdown?

Tags: shutdown, reboot, pcie

When you shut down your computer before it completely powers off, you might see a ton of PCIE error messages quickly scrolling by for a few seconds. How to fix scrolling PCIE errors after reboot / shutdown on a new install of Ubuntu 19.10?

Comment: @Carlos like you is new, with limited rights and commenting via answer is all he could do. I would have provided links to the other questions, but as written I don't actually see your question because you provided your own answer it seems, and it should have been written as such (question, then answer in answer section).

Comment: Please note that by saying "19.x" I mean both 19.04 and 19.10. Sorry for any confusion

Comment: I am currently running 19.10, I just so happened to have the same issue with 19.04 as well. Sorry I should have paid more attention to that link you just provided before posting. Still, I think this is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the Grub Customizer program from the terminal as follows.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt update
sudo apt install grub-customizer
```

This is a very powerful grub customization program, so be careful with it.

Once open, go to the *General Settings* tab. You should see *Kernel Parameters*. It already should have something in there like `quiet splash`, for instance. Add a space after whatever is in there and add `pci=nomsi` so the string should now read `quiet splash pci=nomsi`

Click the *Save* button on the upper left corner and reboot your system with `sudo reboot`.

You should no longer receive these PCIE error messages. This doesn't necessarily mean that the messages aren't being logged somewhere or that you don't have a PCIE issue, but it disables printing to the screen of the several seconds of PCIE error messages that you would otherwise receive.

Comment: Thanks @karei for reformatting this question properly. I appreciate it.